# In Perl, how can a child thread signal to the main thread that no more threads should be created?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm having some problems in returning a value from a thread in perl.

The code I'm using is this:

```
use threads;
foreach $num(1 .. 100)
{
    push(@threads, threads->create (\&readnum, $num));
    sleep(1) while(scalar threads->list(threads::running) >= 10);
}
$_->join foreach @threads;
sub readnum {
    # some code here
}
```

so I want to return a value from readnum i.e:

```
use threads;
foreach $num(1 .. 100)
{
    if($ok)
    {
        push(@threads, threads->create (\&readnum, $num));
        sleep(1) while(scalar threads->list(threads::running) >= 10);
    }
}
$_->join foreach @threads;
sub readnum {
    # some code here
    return $ok ? "1" : "0";
}
```

So I want to check the value of `$ok` if it's true it'll create a new thread.

edit:
what i want is to check for $ok value, if it's true it'll creat a new thread and keep progress else it stop. the same idea without threads :

```
foreach $num(1 .. 100)
{
$ok = readnum($num);
print "runing\n";
die "stoped\n" if $ok eq 1;
}
sub readnum {
    # some code here
$_[0]/5 eq 2 ? return 1 : return 0;
    }
```

but with thread i can't put the returned value in $ok.
hope it's clear now. thanks

Comment: Take a look at `threads->list(threads::joinable)`, get return values by joining them, and update your `@threads`.

Comment: @mpapec could you give more explation ?
thanks

Comment: It is not clear what do you want; to start thread depending on return value, or to keep constant number of running threads? Please, update your question with better explanation.

Comment: @mpapec okay i did update it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not return a value from a thread, but have one thread the ability to signal to the main thread that no more threads should be created. You can do that by creating a [shared global](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html). In the example below, there is a 1/20 chance that a random thread will decide that processing should be stopped.

There may be other, better ways of dealing with your specific problem (for example, each thread pushing results to a shared array, and the main thread checking how many results are there etc), but this seems to match your situation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $KEEP_GOING :shared;
$KEEP_GOING = 1;

my @threads;
THREAD:
for my $num (1 .. 100) {
    sleep 1 while threads->list(threads::running) >= 10;
    {
        lock $KEEP_GOING;
        if($KEEP_GOING) {
            push @threads, threads->create(\&readnum, $num);
        }
        else {
            print "Won't create thread for $num .. Goodbye!\n";
            last THREAD;
        }
    }
}

$_->join for @threads;

sub readnum {
    my $num = shift;
    printf "Thread id: %d\tnum = %d\n", threads->tid, $num;
    sleep 1 + rand(3);
    {
        lock $KEEP_GOING;
        if (0.05 > rand) {
            $KEEP_GOING = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread id: 1    num = 1
Thread id: 2    num = 2
Thread id: 3    num = 3
Thread id: 4    num = 4
Thread id: 5    num = 5
Thread id: 6    num = 6
Thread id: 7    num = 7
Thread id: 8    num = 8
Thread id: 9    num = 9
Thread id: 10   num = 10
Won't create thread for 11 .. Goodbye!
```

Comment: thanks. but i don't think you did understand what i want. sorry for miscofivuration i did update the question :)